# How to add 1 pure html in another html

Tags: html

I am having 1 pure html page for ex. sample.html. I need to include this html into another pure html for ex.Orginal.html.How to do this? I am having a header image in my sample.html.It should come at the top of the Orginal.html page.

Comment: I suppose you want this to be done dynamically? What language do you want to use? Javascript, php, asp.net, ...?

Comment: I understand that he is really talking about plain HTML and nothing else...

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Apache web server, you could try using [server side includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html).

Comment: It seems IIS supports this too

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/eced0b89-e052-42ff-baa8-751dd191c3b5.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 4):

You can't do such things in pure HTML, unless you use frames or iframe element. But better merge them by hand...

Comment: that's my point :)
I'd use something server-side, but if we're talking here about just a handful of files, the best solution would be to just update HTML - if it's pure HTML, they would need editing anyway, so why make it more complicated. In such scenario simple edit is the most pragmatic.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to do it in pure HTML with an iframe, which although strangely not mentioned in HTML 4 specification is supported by all major browsers (and is in the HTML 5 specification)

```
<body>
<h1>This is original page</h1>
<p>Some content on original page.</p>
<iframe src="sample.html" width="600" height="300"></iframe>
</body>
```

You can adjust the width and height and you can also remove the border if you want the page to be more seamless.

Be wary of JavaScript solutions to this problem, especially if you want to be viewed on mobile devices.

Additional note: Avoid frameset solutions also, as they aren't valid markup.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to load some HTML from one document into another. This task is fairly simple using the [jQuery toolkit](http://jquery.com):

```
$("The ID of a container (a div element for instance) in which you want to load
the contents of a HTML file").load("path to html file you want to load");
```

```
<div id="inserthere" />
```

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#inserthere").load("loadme.html"); // Load the contents of loadme.html
                                          // and stuff it in the div with the
                                          // ID of "inserthere"
});
```

Comment: The "file to include" will be visible only when the DOM has finished loading.. and it will also make ajax calls for displaying the content. This ain't gonna look right.

Answer (score 1):

See [Include One File In Another](http://allmyfaqs.net/faq.pl?Include_one_file_in_another), which has a summary of the various techniques that are available (along with their pros and cons).